# Validate a value changed with Jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I'm not quite good at javascript and ajax, so I ask you for help. I use Symfony2 and Twig and I have a field which I change with jediable but its value should be unique. So I check this in the controller action, but I can't succeed in making the app to act normally. I tried a lot of things and the closest to the result I want is this:

```
   if (count($same) == 0) {
            // add to database
        } else { 
                $response = new Response();
                $response->setContent('<div class="alert alert-error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">OK</button>
            <strong>This value is already used!</strong> Please choose another.
        </div>');
                $response->send();
```

which outputs this nice error:

[image]

but when I click OK, the jeditable pluging is still working, and the whole error becomes editable, so the value of the input field contains all the HTML set in `$response->setContent()`[image]

Because the  the whole block

```
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">OK</button>
            <strong>This value is already used!</strong> Please choose another.
        </div>
```

is in the div with the class '.edit' when I click it, it becomes editable and contains this whole block. What I want is when the user clicks on the alert generated in the controller to return to input field from jeditable with a value as the original name of the category before he started to edit or with empty value.

This is my .js file but it doesn't make the input field empty (but it prints wokring) :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('.edit').editable(path, {
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'Save',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit'
     });

     $('.bla').on('click','.alert', function(){        
         console.log('working');    
         $("input[type=text]").hmtl('');
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<span class="right-spacer"><strong id="{{cat.id}}"class="edit bla">{{ cat.name }}</strong>
```

Any ideas for solution?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, your popup error is created dynamically when someone click on the button "Save" with an invalid value, this means that the pop-up does not exists at the `$(document).ready` time. This is why this part:

```
$('.alert').on('click', function(){
    $("input[type=text]").val('');
});
```

Will never be executed. If you want this function to work, you will need to use delegation, as you use Jquery this will be pretty easy.

Instead of `$('.alert').on('click', function(){`

You will have to use something like `$('body').on('click','.alert', function(){`

Where body is an element that is a parent of `.alert`, for exemple if you know your pop-up will be created inside a div with the id of first_div(Something like `<div id="first_div">`) You would put instead `$('#first_div').on('click','.alert', function(){`

This means that the div will listen to the click events inside him, so the closer he is to the pop-up the more efficient it is.

Comment: If it prints "working" it is a good thing, it means the function is executed. $("input") is a pretty vague selector, is it not possible for you to give the input an ID and call him like this: 

    $("#input_id")

I also see that you put .html('') but that is not going to work, you need to use .val('')

Answer (score 4):

I think this was missing,

```
if (count($same) == 0) {
    // add to database
    // clear the content on form. 
    //$("input[type=text]").html('');//it should be html not **hmtl**
}
```

Try and reply if not done..

This should do..

Comment: Note: actually that will go in else part also.. or just call a `function reset(){$("input[type=text]").html('');}` on press of OK button.. :)